# Kubernetes best practices in pods

Tags: kubernetes, containers, devops

As I have been using kubernetes more I keep on seeing the reference that a pod can contain 1 container or more and I have even looked at examples.

My question is whether there is a case where this would be best practice and more efficient to create multi container pods since you can scale and replicate your pods coupling it with a service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Pod can contain multiple containers, but for the most portion of the situations, it makes perfect sense for the Pod to be simply an abstraction over a single running container.

**In what situations does it make sense to have a multi-container deployed Pod?**

What comes to my mind are the scenarios where you have a primary Pod running, but you need to tightly couple helper processes, such as a log watcher. In those situations, it makes perfect sense to actually have multiple containers running inside a single pod.

Another big example that comes to my mind is from the [Istio](https://istio.io/) project, which is a platform made to connect, manage and secure microservices and is generally referred as a Service Mesh.

A huge part of what it does and is able to accomplish to provide a greater control and customization over the deployed microservices network, is due to the fact that it deploys a sidecar proxy, denominated Envoy, throughout the environment intercepting all network communication between microservices.

[Here](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/load-balancing.html), you can check an example of load balancing in a Istio service mesh. As you can see the Proxy is deployed inside the Pod, intercepting all communication that goes through it.